# CsrfPreventionFilter

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, csrf

I think that the following question may be naive, but I want to use the Csrf prevention filter of Tomcat and having a hard time configuring it. So, can someone provide me with some sort of sample code on how to do it? I am apache tomcat 6.0.33.

Thanks in advance.